# how to return ValueKeyPair or something else if pair wasn't found?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dictionary, key-value

I have a Dictionary<> built from Vehicle(key) and Owner(value).
I have a method that searches a ValueKeyPair by a given Vehicle's license number, and if it finds it,
it returns the valueKeyPair of that found license.

but if during the search the method doesn't find a matched Key, then what should it return?
it seems that a ValueKeyPair cannot be initialize to NULL, so i cant return null.

Can you advise me what to do?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post the code that is particularly giving you trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming both `Key` and `Value` are of type String, you can return default value of **`KeyValuePair<string, string>`** like this:

```
return default(KeyValuePair<string, string>);
```

and code where you are checking, you can check for null value of key.

**OR**

Modify your method to return **`nullable KeyValuePair`** which enables you to return null.
Replace return type from `KeyValuePair<string, string>` to `KeyValuePair<string, string>?`.

```
private KeyValuePair<string, string>? MethodName()
{   
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use TryGetValue in an if statement?

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx
```